# Creating a many-to-many relationship in EF6 code first

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first

I'm trying to use code first to create a many-to-many relationship between two tables.

I have something that looks like the following.

```
public class Railroad
{

    public int Id { get; set; }

    // Other members...

    public ICollection<StorageLocation> StorageLocations { get; set; }

}

public class StorageLocation
{

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public Provider Provider { get; set; }

    // Other members

    public ICollection<Railroad> Railroads { get; set; }

}
```

I read [an article](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx) that described this being the correct way to do it. But when I try to build the migration, I get an error.

> Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation property 'Railroad.StorageLocations' of type 'ICollection'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.

Comment: This should do it, but there may be other navigation properties that interfere. Could you show all navigation properties if there are more?

Comment: @GertArnold: There is one, which I've added. `Provider` itself has no navigation properties. I don't see how that could cause problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you're not on `EF Core`?
this has been supported before but not now in EF Core:

See [this](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/many-to-many-relationship-configuration)

> In previous versions of Entity Framework, this model definition was sufficient for EF to imply the correct type of relationship and to generate the join table for it. In EF Core it is necessary to include an entity in the model to represent the join table, and then add navigation properties to either side of the many-to-many relations that point to the join entity instead:

Comment: Seems pathetic to me how many working features we have given up for the privilege of working with .NET Core. I'm using .NET Core 3. Not sure when this article was written.

Comment: EF6.3 and higher support .net standard 2.1, so being in .net core 3 still doesn't tell which EF version you're using. It could be 6.4.4 (current EF6 version) or EF-core 3. Probably the latter.

Comment: @GertArnold Thanks for your interesting point, it seems in this case it's the latter based on error :)

Comment: @GertArnold: Does it make a difference? Do you have information that this has been implemented in a newer version? I'm not sure right off how to see which version I'm using but I'm using Visual Studio 16.6.0 and just created the project, so I assume it's the latest to ship with VS.

Comment: EF6.3+ is just the old and trusted EF6 but ported to .net standard 2.1. Nothing in this area (many to many) "has been implemented" recently. EF core doesn't support it and it doesn't have any priority there.

Comment: @GertArnold Looks like it's the [top one in 5.0 plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-5.0/plan#many-to-many-navigation-properties-aka-skip-navigations) with Status: In-progress.

Comment: @Ivan Too bad :). Never understood why it's so important.

Comment: @IvanStoev: Sounds well. This issue beside some limitations in `Group by` are really bothering!